# json api plugin error in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, json-api

I'm using `json api plugin` to fetch data as json records in my wo site.
Now when I run my site in local host it runs without any problem.
but when I upload my site to the host when I run my site to get json data I face with this error

`Something went wrong fetching URL with JSON-data: Failed to connect to localhost port 88: Connection refusederror: get of json-data failed - plugin aborted: check url of json-feed`

Comment: what process is running in port 88 in localhost (your machine)? Same process needs to run in your hosting server as well. Your hosting server has blocked access to port 88. Paste code as well.

Comment: my machine's 80 port is occupied so I reconfing post number to 88 in my apache server. It runs successfully on my machine but after upload on host I face with that error. I know that my error occurred after upload. But I couldn't find the error solution

Comment: what about the hosting server port? I believe it is running in port 80 and most shared hosting account do not allow to run server other than 80.